# After adding feature module in Android getting error "Error:Non-base feature modules require AAPTv2 to build."

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

In Android for Instant app after adding feature module getting below error "Error:Non-base feature modules require AAPTv2 to build."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that in gradle.properties "android.enableAapt2" is set true